# Finding $z$ satisfying $2z=(3+4i)\bar z$, $z\bar z=2$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find the complex number $z$ satisfying both equations:
>   $$5z=(3+4i)\bar z\\z\bar z=5$$

sorry, question has been revised..

Comment: Minor question: does $z^*$ denote the conjugate of $z$ here?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I believe they are merely notational alternatives.

Comment: I figured as much, just wanted to check since I've only seen the bar notation as in Saad's edit

Comment: something is wrong here since taking absolute values (and noting $z \neq 0$) one gets $2=5$!

Comment: The first equation cannot hold unless $z=0$ (in which case, the second equation does not hold). The problem is cacked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $z=x+yi,$ where $x$ and $y$ are reals.
Thus, $$5(x+yi)=(3+4i)(x-yi),$$ which gives $x=2y$.

Also, we have $x^2+y^2=5.$

Can you end it now?

Comment: I've tried another way of doing, which I let the real part of the first equation, x²-y² = 3 to be equation 1, the real part of second equation, x²+y² = 2 to be equation 2, then solve x and y simultaneously, is this way of solving correct?

Comment: @Jason Yeap You can not get from the first equation $x^2-y^2=3$ because the first equation is homogeneous. From the first equation we obtain $x^2+y^2=0.$

Comment: what about this?
2(x + iy) = (3 + 4i)(x - iy) , 
2x + 2yi = 3x - 3yi + 4xi + 4y , 
2x + 2yi = 3x + 4y + (4x - 3y)i , 
comparing the real part of this equation , 
2x = 3x + 4y , 
x = -4y -------- (1) , 
Substitute (1) into second equation , 
x^2 + y^2 = 2 , 
17y^2 = 2 , 
y = ±√(2/17) , x = ±4√(2/17) , 
with this, z = √(2/17) - 4√(2/17)i , -√(2/17) + 4√(2/17)i

Comment: @Jason Yeap You got $2x+2yi=3x+4y+(4x-3y)i,$ which gives $x=-4y$ and $4x=5y$, which is $x=y=0.$

Comment: sorry, there's some revision to the question... edited the question

Comment: yes.. wait.. isnt it x² + y² = 5??

Comment: @Jason Yeap Yes, I fixed. It does not change the essence.

Comment: thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use both rectangular or polar representation of the complex number to solve this.
$$5z=(3+4i)\bar z$$
$$z\bar z=5$$
We know that : $$z\bar z=|z|^2=5$$
so,  $$|z|=\sqrt 5$$

Put $z=|z|e^{i\theta}=\sqrt5 e^{i\theta}$ in the first equation,

$$5\sqrt5e^{i\theta}=(3+4i)\sqrt5e^{-i\theta}$$
$$e^{2i\theta}=\frac{(3+4i)}{5}$$
Now, 
$$\cos{2\theta}+i\sin{2\theta}=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{4i}{5}$$
Solve, $$\cos {2\theta}=\frac{3}{5}$$ and $$\sin {2\theta}=\frac{4}{5}$$ simultaneously to get the value of $\theta$.

Final answer is: $z=\sqrt5 e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta=\frac{1}{2}\tan^{-1} \frac{4}{3}$
Hope this helps...